Persistent Bluetooth Issue on Dual-Booted Ubuntu 20.04 - "No default controller available" and Unable to Init Device
I am experiencing a persistent Bluetooth issue on my dual-booted system running Ubuntu 20.04 and could use some help troubleshooting further. Below are the details and steps I've tried so far:
System Details:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (part of a dual-boot setup)
Bluetooth Utility: bluetoothctl, hciconfig
Bluetooth Service Status: Active and running

Issue Description:
Initially, my Bluetooth was not detecting any devices. When attempting to use bluetoothctl scan on, I received "No default controller available." Further attempts to activate the controller using hciconfig hci0 up resulted in "Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)."
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Checked the status of the Bluetooth service using systemctl status bluetooth - the service is active.
Verified if the device was soft/hard blocked using rfkill list all - no blocks present.
Checked the Bluetooth controller presence and status using bluetoothctl list and hciconfig -a - the controller appears but is in a DOWN state.
Attempted to manually start the Bluetooth controller with sudo hciconfig hci0 up, which led to a timeout error.
Reloaded Bluetooth drivers (modprobe -r btusb and modprobe btusb).
Updated the system and checked for additional drivers (sudo apt update, upgrade, and ubuntu-drivers autoinstall).
Rebooted multiple times throughout the process.

Kernel and Hardware Checks:

lsusb:

    $ lsusb
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3151:3020 YICHIP Wireless Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0e2 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'

[    0.097639] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.268409] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.395737] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    1.395749] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    1.395750] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.395753] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.395754] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.395756] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.743018] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x04000022
[    1.744159] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.21 DEC: 2 VEP: 0 Revision: 10
[    1.744171] amdgpu 0000:06:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    1.797013] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20220322164011
[    1.833901] mt7921e 0000:03:00.0: Firmware init done
[    3.471483] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.471486] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.471491] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[16214.768765] audit: type=1107 audit(1716545549.831:66): pid=1100 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=775472 label="snap.notion-snap-reborn.notion-snap-reborn" peer_pid=1085 peer_label="unconfined"


However, hciconfig lists the controller with an address of 00:00:00:00:00:00 and it is marked as DOWN.

Despite these steps, the system still does not recognize any Bluetooth controller for operational use. Has anyone faced a similar issue or have suggestions on what else I could try, especially considering the dual-boot configuration? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'

@Jeremy31 Done, thanks.

What kernel is used?  uname -r

@Jeremy31 5.15.0-107-generic

In terminal check mokutil --sb as Secure Boot must be disabled, then
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.15.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-5.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
Reboot
